# With fitvids.js Library, Video is Shown but There is No Way to Control by Code

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, video

I'm using fitvids.js and my HTML is this:

```
<div class="fitvids">
      <iframe src="video/myVideo.mp4" width="500" height="281" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

The video is shown as it should, but the problem is that I can not control my video (pause, play, ...) through jQuery/JavaScript using my custom "Pause Me" button. When I "alert" the content of the iframe tag through:

```
alert($("iframe").html());
```

, I see an empty message. There is no sign of the video tag in the alert and I know that without video tag I cannot pause/play my video through code.

I hope I have provided enough info for you guys to help me out break this lock.

Comment: Where is the video hosted? If it's on another domain (e.g. youtube) you won't have much (if any) script access to the iframe's contents. This is due to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Also, the iframe src should point at an HTML document which contains a video element, not directly at the video file!

Comment: Thanks "Olly Hodgson," insightful.